# Matlab - bug with multiple inputs

Tags: function, matlab

This is my function:

```
function [o1  o2] = f(t, y)
o1 = y(2);
o2 = -sin(y(1));
end
```

When I call it from command prompt:

```
f(1, [2,3])
ans = 3
```

why do I only see `o1`?
Also, this doesn't work

```
feval(f, 1, [2 3])
```

The error message is

```
Input argument "y" is undefined.

Error in ==> f at 2
o1 = y(2);
```

Please help, I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

If you just call the function without explicit output variable, it will only return the first  output argument, which is `o1` and assign it to the bit-bucket, `ans`. To get both outputs, do the following.

```
[o1,o2]=f(1, [2,3])
```

To use [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html), you should pass a function handle, which is the name of the function preceded by an `@` sign. So, `feval(@f,1,[2,3])` should work.

Answer (score 3):

feval should have been called with a function handle or string, so use

```
feval(@f, 1, [2,3])
```

or

```
feval('f', 1, [2,3])
```

As you will see this also returns just the first output of the function. To receive further outputs you must assign them, e.g.

```
[o1, o2] = feval(@f, 1, [2, 3])
```

Comment: The function handle version is preferable.