# Matlab - how to make this work for both scalars and vectors

Tags: function, matlab

Suppose function g takes a function f as a parameter, and inside g we have something like
x = t*feval(f, u);
however, f can be either scalar-valued or vector-valued. If it is vector valued, we want x to be a vector as well, i.e. the feval statement to return the whole vector returned by f. How do we make this work for both scalar and vector cases?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, what you are asking is already the default behavior in matlab. 
This means that if f returns a scalar, x will be a scalar and if it returns a vector x will be a vector.

In your example, this holds as long as t is also a scalar - otherwise the result will depend on how t*[output of f] is evaluated.

***Example***

```
function o1 = f(N)
o1 = zeros(1,N);
end
```

Here f returns a scalar if N=1 and a vector for N>1. 
Calling your code gives

```
x=feval('f', 1); % Returns x = 0

x=feval('f', 4); % Returns x = [0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for me:function [o1  o2] = f(t, y)
o1 = y(2);
o2 = -sin(y(1));
end then I call > x = feval('f' , 1, [1 1])

x =

     1
Any ideas? Got stuck on this one

Comment: I think I got it, I should have function x = f(t, y) as method signature, i.e. x instead of [01, 02]

Comment: @glup : Actually with your first function definition, x will simply be given the value of o1 - but this issue is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734858/matlab-bug-with-multiple-inputs).

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `feval(f,u)` can be either a scalar or a vector, and you want the result `x` to be the same (i.e. a scalar or a vector of the same length and dimension), then it will depend on what `t` is:

- If `t` is a scalar, then what you have is fine. You can use either of the operators `*` or `.*` to perform the multiplication.
- If `t` is a vector of the same length and dimension as the result from `feval(f,u)`, then use the `.*` operator to perform element-wise multiplication.
- If `t` is a vector of the same length but with *different* dimension that the result from `feval(f,u)` (i.e. one is a row vector and one is a column vector), then you have to make the dimensions match by transposing one or the other with the `.'` operator.
- If `t` is a different length than the result of `feval(f,u)`, then you can't do element-wise multiplication.